# Executing the same batch file in all subfolders with spaces in the subfolder names

Tags: command-line, batch-file, subdirectory

I have many sub-folders in a root folder and I want to run the same batch file in each sub-folder.
The sub-folders might well have spaces in their names.
The batch file I want to run just appends all of the mp3 files in the sub-folder into one larger mp3 file and then deletes the individual mp3 files and I already have this batch file and run it manually in each sub-folder now.
There is a varying number of sub-folders and a varying number of mp3 files in each sub-folder

The Root folder is: `D:\Audioedit` and the existing batch file to append and delete is named `mm.bat`

My last (of many) attempts, running from the command line was:

```
for / f %f in<'dir /ad /b'> do start mm.bat
```

which does not work.  I've tried to follow the related threads here, but I am not a programmer and most of it flies over my head.

Comment: It looks like I found one posted by foxidrive that will work for me ....  

@echo off
for /r /d %%f in (*) do pushd "%%f" & Call "callshow.bat" & popd

Thanks in any case !

Comment: If it worked for you, you should accept his answer below

Answer (score 1):

This should work: reduce all %% to % if you want to run it from the command line.

```
for /r /d "d:\audioedit" %%a in (*) do pushd "%%a" & call mm.bat & popd
```

A comment about your task: if the MP3s have different bitrates and sampling rates etc then it may not play properly.  If they do share the same parameters then there can still be a dislocation in the audio at the join.  You may like to look at `freemake audio converter` which is free GUI software, and autoit could help run it in a stack of folders.  `Sox` is a command line audio converter.